# Как изменить цвет у material design button?

Tags: android, material-design

Решил переделать все приложение в `Material design` и не понимаю как сделать фон кнопки, сейчас вот так:

```
 android:background="@drawable/check_background"
```

Можно ли вообще через `drawable`, потому что через `backgroundtint` вообще не такой внешний вид у кнопки становится, какой должен быть

Answer (score 1):

Да через `drawable` можно, но формы кнопки напрямую будут зависеть от `drawable`.

Так же можно изменить цвет через стиль

```
<style name="CustomButtonMaterial" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/RedButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
<style name="RedButtonThemeOverlay">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

И применив его к кнопке

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/CustomButtonMaterial"
    .../>
```

---

Чем вас `backgroundtint` не устроил? (Именно его [рекомендовано](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons) использовать)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что не было никаких изменений. в итоге, я просто добавил цвет в color и добавил свойства (округление (оно почему то не работало вне drawable не в material)
кстати, с стилем оно тоже почему то не поменялось